# How to sort a multi-dimensional Arraylist "ArrayList<String[]>" in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I wrote a code to sort a multidimensional ArrayList `ArrayList<String[]>` by the 1st element of each `String[]`, the 2dArray looks like this:

```
{
 ["Mark", "mark@mail.com"],
 ["Angela", "zzAngela@gmail.com"],
 ["Harry", "abc_harry@hotmail.com"],
 ["Donald","donny@aol.com"]
}
```

But when I run the code the array doesn't get sorted, can someone explain what is wrong with my code? Thank you already!

```
ArrayList<String[]> sorter = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String file_name = "db_email.csv";

// READING FROM CSV FILE & STORING DATA INTO 2dARRAY
try{

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file_name));

    String line = reader.readLine(); // read the rest
    String[] row;

    while(line != null){

    String[] result = line.split(","); 
    sorter.add(new String[]{result[0], result[1]});
    line = reader.readLine();
    }

    reader.close(); 
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}

// MY SORTING ALGORITHM
Collections.sort(sorter, new Comparator<String[]>() { 

    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
    }               
});
```

```
// EXPECTED RESULT (sorting 2dArray by 1st column):
{
 ["Angela", "zzAngela@gmail.com"],
 ["Donald","donny@aol.com"],
 ["Harry", "abc_harry@hotmail.com"],
 ["Mark", "mark@mail.com"]
}

// ACTUAL RESULT (the array doesn't get sorted):
{
 ["Mark", "mark@mail.com"],
 ["Angela", "zzAngela@gmail.com"],
 ["Harry", "abc_harry@hotmail.com"],
 ["Donald","donny@aol.com"]
}
```

Comment: Why are you using arrays to store data, instead of creating `Person` objects for your `ArrayList`?  What is the contents of your file?

Comment: Your code produces the expected result when I run it locally and dump the contents of "sorter" after the call to `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: It works as expected. Are you sure that you didn't `print` the ArrayList before calling `sort`?

Comment: @HieuHT with a for loop I print ```sorter``` again, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @rgettman I will lately rewrite the CSV file, I'm only using arrays to temporary store the values

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue, I was testing the sorting algorithm by adding a line like "aaaaa,myname@mail.com". I was unaware of the capitalization issue (probably bc it compares the numerical Unicode value), therefore the above line was always placed last. When I tested with a normal line like "Peter White,peter@me.com" it was working as expected.

Thank you all for your help & suggestions!